400 bad request with complex POJO object in Micronaut HTTP get method
@Serdeable
public record FilterSortRequest(@JsonProperty("filters")List<FilterOption> filters, @JsonProperty("sorts")Map<String, SortOperators> sorts) {
}

Micronaut Controller
@Controller("/tag")
@Version("1")
@Tag(name = "Tag")
public class TagController implements IHttpAction<TagRequest, TagResponse> {
   
    public TagController(IServiceAction<FilterSortRequest, TagRequest, TagResponse> iServiceAction) {
        this.iServiceAction = iServiceAction;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse<?> find(@QueryValue FilterSortRequest searchCriteria) {
        var result = this.iServiceAction.find(searchCriteria);
        return Result.match(()-> HttpResponse.ok(result.value), ()->HttpResponse.notFound(result.exception.getMessage()));
    }
}

Http client
@Validated
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
public interface IHttpAction<C, T, R> {

    @Get(value = "/{?searchCriteria*}")
    HttpResponse<?> find(@QueryValue FilterSortRequest searchCriteria);


    @Get(uri = "/{id}")
    HttpResponse<?> get(@PathVariable(name = "id") @Nonnull UUID id);


    @Post
    HttpResponse<?> post(@Body T request);


    @Put(uri = "/{id}")
    HttpResponse<?> put(@PathVariable(name = "id") @NotNull UUID id, @Body T request);

    @Delete(uri = "/{id}")
    HttpResponse<?> delete(@PathVariable(name = "id") @NotNull UUID id);
}

Register the Binder as
@Singleton
public class FilterSortRequestBinder implements TypedRequestArgumentBinder<FilterSortRequest> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public FilterSortRequestBinder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Argument<FilterSortRequest> argumentType() {
        return Argument.of(FilterSortRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public BindingResult<FilterSortRequest> bind(ArgumentConversionContext<FilterSortRequest> context, HttpRequest<?> source) {
        try {
            // Extract the 'filters' parameter
            String filtersParam = source.getParameters().get("filters");
            // Extract the 'sorts' parameter
            String sortsParam = source.getParameters().get("sorts");

            // Deserialize filters and sorts
            List<FilterOption> filters = filtersParam != null
                    ? objectMapper.readValue(filtersParam, Argument.listOf(FilterOption.class))
                    : Collections.emptyList();

            Map<String, SortOperators> sorts = sortsParam != null
                    ? objectMapper.readValue(sortsParam, Argument.mapOf(String.class, SortOperators.class))
                    : Collections.emptyMap();

            // Create the FilterSortRequest object
            FilterSortRequest filterSortRequest = new FilterSortRequest(filters, sorts);
            return () -> Optional.of(filterSortRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return BindingResult.EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

The execution never hits the bind method.
Sending the request as
http://localhost:8080/tag?filters=[{"field":"string","operator":"EQUAL","values":{"additionalProp1":"string","additionalProp2":"string","additionalProp3":"string"}}]&sorts={"additionalProp1":"ASC","additionalProp2":"ASC","additionalProp3":"ASC"}

400 bad request
{
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "/tag?filters=%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22EQUAL%22%2C%22values%22%3A%7B%22additionalProp1%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22additionalProp2%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22additionalProp3%22%3A%22string%22%7D%7D%5D&sorts=%7B%22additionalProp1%22%3A%22ASC%22%2C%22additionalProp2%22%3A%22ASC%22%2C%22additionalProp3%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D",
        "templated": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Failed to convert argument [searchCriteria] for value [null] due to: Unexpected token VALUE_STRING, expected START_OBJECT \n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]",
        "path": "/searchCriteria"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "Bad Request"
}


I have to write a custom binder to handle complex objects. Remove @QueryValue and  (value = "/{?searchCriteria*}") from the HttpAction
@Validated
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
public interface IHttpAction<T, R> {

    @Get
    HttpResponse<?> find(FilterSortRequest searchCriteria);
}


@Singleton
public class FilterSortRequestBinder implements TypedRequestArgumentBinder<FilterSortRequest> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public FilterSortRequestBinder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }


    @Override
    public Argument<FilterSortRequest> argumentType() {
        return Argument.of(FilterSortRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public BindingResult<FilterSortRequest> bind(ArgumentConversionContext<FilterSortRequest> context, HttpRequest<?> source) {
        try {
            // Extract the 'filters' parameter
            String filtersParam = source.getParameters().get("filters");
            // Extract the 'sorts' parameter
            var sortsParam = source.getParameters().get("sorts");

            // Deserialize filters and sorts
            List<FilterOption> filters = filtersParam != null
                    ? objectMapper.readValue(filtersParam, Argument.listOf(FilterOption.class))
                    : Collections.emptyList();

            List<SortOption> sorts = sortsParam != null
                    ? objectMapper.readValue(sortsParam, Argument.listOf(SortOption.class))
                    : Collections.emptyList();

            // Create the FilterSortRequest object
            FilterSortRequest filterSortRequest = new FilterSortRequest(filters, sorts);
            return () -> Optional.of(filterSortRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return BindingResult.EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

